# htaccess RewriteCond to redirect and hyperlinks pointing to main domain to a subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I need some assistance with htaccess and RewriteCond.

On my subdomain http://staging.foo.com/ I want to rewrite any hyperlinks with http://foo.org.uk as a prefix to my subdomain http://staging.foo.org.uk by means of .htaccess.

Any ideas of what to put into the .htaccess file on staging.foo.com?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is actually possible - so any pointers would be welcome.

Comment: you want to redirect or rewrite ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with mod_rewrite. It only acts on requests to the server, not content that is returned to the browser.

You could do something with PHP using prepend and append scripts. In the prepend script turn on output buffering, then in the append script get the output buffer contents, search/replace, then output again.